# Forma correcta de formatear JSON

Tags: json, vb.net

Soy nuevo con el `JSON` y estoy tratando de crear un `String` de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    "preference_id":"Preference_ID" ,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "category_id": null,
            "currency_id": "ARS",
            "description": "asd",
            "picture_url": null,
            "title": "1",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit_price": 1
        }
    ],
    "marketplace": "1234323",
    "external_reference": "default",
    "additional_info": "additional information"
}
```

Pero cuando yo lo genero, no encuentro la forma que me aparezcan los corchetes `[]` después del `items`. El código que yo genero queda de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "preference_id":"preference_id",
  "items":
        {
            "id":1,
            "category_id":"gase001",
          "currency_id":"[FAKER][CURRENCY][ACRONYM]",
          "description":"Gaseosa 350ml",
          "picture_url":"picture",
          "title":"Gaseosa 350",
          "quantity":1,
          "unit_price":1
        },
  "marketplace":"None",
  "external_reference":"Defaults",
  "additional_info":"algo"
}
```

Para realizar este código utilizo las siguiente clases:

```
 Public Class Preference
        <JsonProperty("preference_id")>
        Public preference_id As String
        <JsonProperty("items")>
        Public items As Items
        <JsonProperty("marketplace")>
        Public marketplace As String
        <JsonProperty("external_reference")>
        Public external_reference As String
        <JsonProperty("additional_info")>
        Public additional_info As String
end Class 

Public Class Items
    <JsonProperty("id")>
    Public id As Integer
    <JsonProperty("category_id")>
    Public category_id As Object
    <JsonProperty("currency_id")>
    Public currency_id As String
    <JsonProperty("description")>
    Public description As String
    <JsonProperty("picture_url")>
    Public picture_url As String
    <JsonProperty("title")>
    Public title As String
    <JsonProperty("quantity")>
    Public quantity As Integer
    <JsonProperty("unit_price")>
    Public unit_price As Integer
end class
```

Y este es parte del código que utilizo para la generación del `JSON` el cual me lo genera sin los corchetes como lo mencione anteriormente.

```
 Dim orden As Preference = New Preference With {
                .preference_id = asd,
                .additional_info = "asd",
                .external_reference = "Defaults",
                .marketplace = "None",
                .items = New Items With {
                .id = "0001",
                .category_id = "gase001",
                .currency_id = "[FAKER][CURRENCY][ACRONYM]",
                .description = "Gaseosa 350ml",
                .picture_url = "picture",
                .title = "Gaseosa 350",
                .quantity = 1,
                .unit_price = 1
            }
       }

            Dim result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orden)
```

Answer (score 0):

antes que todo aviso que a lo mejor no te voy a proporcionar una manera definitiva, pero te voy a dar al menos la que yo ocupo.

Cuando llamo elementos desde el backend, estos los meto a una lista **JSON** que creo con objetos:

```
Dim jsonlist as New List(of Object)
```

Luego, cuando llamo los elementos de mi tabla lo guardo todo en un adapter, en mi caso es **Npgsql**

```
Dim ds as New Dataset()
Using sda As New NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    sda.Fill(ds,"data")
End Using
```

y finalmente, creo una lista de objetos para que se pueda leer de la manera correcta en ajax

```
For Each table as Datatable in ds.Tables
    Dim rowValues As New List(Of List(Of Object))
    For Each column as DataColumn In table.Columns
        If row.IsNull(column)Then
            values.Add("")'Importante, si tiene valores vacios la lista crasheara
        Else
            values.Add(row.Item(column).ToString().Trim())
        End If
    Next
    rowValues.add(values)
Next
jsonList.Add(rowValues)

Return jsonList
```

Finalmente, en el success de ajax escribo lo siguiente:

```
var dData = JSON.stringify(data.d['0']);
data = JSON.parse(dData);
```

Y con esas 2 lineas, me queda un objeto ajax compatible con todo tipo de plugins, como [dataTables JS](https://datatables.net/).

Ocupar una clase para un formato no es necesario, solo se deben llamar de una manera admisible para parsear con **JSON**

Si tienes alguna duda, por favor escríbeme para solucionarla.

Answer (score 0):

Para tener la salida del **json** que esperas debes de declarar el campo **`items`** de la clase **`Preference`** como una lista.

Tu clase **`Preference`** quedaría así:

```
Public Class Preference
    <JsonProperty("preference_id")>
    Public preference_id As String
    <JsonProperty("items")>
    Public items As List(Of Items) REM este campo debe ser una lista
    <JsonProperty("marketplace")>
    Public marketplace As String
    <JsonProperty("external_reference")>
    Public external_reference As String
    <JsonProperty("additional_info")>
    Public additional_info As String
End Class
```

Y donde creas el objeto **`orden`** así:

```
Dim orden As Preference = New Preference With {
    .preference_id = "asd",
    .additional_info = "asd",
    .external_reference = "Defaults",
    .marketplace = "None",
    .items = New List(Of Items) From {
        New Items With {
            .id = "0001",
            .category_id = "gase001",
            .currency_id = "[FAKER][CURRENCY][ACRONYM]",
            .description = "Gaseosa 350ml",
            .picture_url = "picture",
            .title = "Gaseosa 350",
            .quantity = 1,
            .unit_price = 1
        }
    }
}

Dim result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orden, Formatting.Indented)
```

> Nota: le pase un segundo parámetro al método **`SerializeObject`** para tabular la salida del **json**.

De esta forma la salida seria:

```
{
  "preference_id": "Preference_ID",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "category_id": "gase001",
      "currency_id": "[FAKER][CURRENCY][ACRONYM]",
      "description": "Gaseosa 350ml",
      "picture_url": "picture",
      "title": "Gaseosa 350",
      "quantity": 1,
      "unit_price": 1
    }
  ],
  "marketplace": "None",
  "external_reference": "Defaults",
  "additional_info": "asd"
}
```